# Who should be allowed access to /etc/kubernetes/pki/ca.crt?

Tags: certificates, kubernetes

Beginners' question.

Who would you allow access to /etc/kubernetes/pki/ca.crt?

What damage to you cluster if someone is not a cluster administrator has got access (e.g. copying and distributing, update/remove it) to the certificate?

If it were updated or removed what would happen to the certifates that were signed using the pair /etc/kubernetes/pki/ca.crt and /etc/kubernetes/pki/ca.key? Will they become invalid?

Answer (score 0):

In terms of read-only access that file is not generally sensitive (there is some minor information disclosure available from it, but not something most cluster operators seem to be concerned about). Allowing easy access to it, allows clients connecting to the API server (and any other certificates signed by that CA) to validate their connection.

Allowing it to be modified/replaced would depend on where and how it was done. If it was done by modifying the `kube-root-ca.crt` configmap that Kubernetes provides, then it could cause connections to the cluster to fail as the client wouldn't be able to validate the connection.

If it was done by changing the file on the control plane node(s) that could be more serious especially as rights to change that file (generally set to 644 root:root) would allow the attacker to read and modify the ca.key file. In that case the attacker would effectively have full control of the cluster.